# Check OAuth Facebook token from iOS client on server/API

Tags: ios, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have an iOS application that connects via Facebook (FBSDK). The authentication is successful on the app and I can check FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().

My iOS app is communicating with a Node API, and I would like to send the FB tokens and check they are valid in every request.

My currentAccessToken on the iOS client looks like: 0x12de32171
I've been trying to check it from https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=0x12de32171 but I have the "Invalid OAuth access token." error everytime

Comment: That does not look like an access token, but rather like a hexadecimal number value.

Comment: Woah I can't believe I was so stupid... You're absolutely right. The token string can be accessed through: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() is an object. To get the token string, it's FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

Then https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE works totally fine